# Authenticate without Requiring a user to Login?

Tags: facebook, authentication

Alright, so here's the situation:
We have a private Facebook group for internal use in our company. We are creating a site to aggregate information from a number of places, one of those being the private Facebook group. I'd like to grab the private Facebook feed and publish it on our aggregate page, without ever requiring a user to log in.

My initial thoughts were to either 1) use a single authentication token which doesn't expire (which doesn't appear to exist) or 2) have user credentials stored (hard-coded in a config file or whatever) and pass those to get the token (which appears Facebook doesn't support).

Is there any way to do this? Am I missing something that Facebook does/doesn't support?
I'm completely new to Facebook dev and only familiar with what I've read recently. Any help, ideas or work-arounds are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are a member of the group, and will remain one you could try something like this:

Set up a private page on your internal server that uses the instructions for the [Server-Side Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) workflow to gain an Auth token in your name and extend this for 60 days. Store the token, your user id and its expiration time locally.

Pass this information to your scraper script that grabs information from the Facebook group as needed and generates your "public" internal page.

As a part of the scrape process, examine the stored token. If it's going to expire in less than 30 days, have the script email you a link to the private page to renew your auth token. (You'll probably want to put some kind of limit in there to keep it from bugging you more than once a day).